# Specific abilities does not work as expected

Tags: nestjs, authorization, casl

I'm using `casl` with a `Nest.js` project and I have a problem.

I want to deny users to read collections unless they are public.
My entity class looks like

```ts
class Collection {
  isPrivate?: boolean
}
```

My `casl` factory looks like

```ts
allow(Action.READ, Collection, { isPublic: true })`
```

So I want to allow reading collection ONLY if it is public.
Currently, when I try `ability.can(Action.READ, Collection)` (so for a list) it returns `true`. I want it to return `false` because it's not public.

Now I give you complete code so you are able to understand the context.

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import {
  AbilityBuilder,
  createMongoAbility,
  ExtractSubjectType,
  InferSubjects,
  MongoAbility,
} from '@casl/ability';
import { JwtPayload, Role } from '../../authentication/types';
import { Action } from '../constants/action';
import { Collection } from '../../collection/entities/collection.entity';
import { User } from '../../user/entities/user.entity';
import { Media } from '../../media/entities/media.entity';

type Subjects =
  | InferSubjects<
      typeof Collection | typeof User | typeof Media | Collection | User | Media
    >
  | 'all';

export type AppAbility = MongoAbility<[Action, Subjects]>;

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationAbilityFactory {
  createForUser(user?: JwtPayload) {
    const {
      can: allow,
      cannot: deny,
      build,
    } = new AbilityBuilder<AppAbility>(createMongoAbility);

    allow(Action.READ, Collection, { isPublic: true }).because(
      'Public collections can be read',
    );
    allow(Action.READ, Media);

    if (user?.role !== Role.USER) {
      allow(Action.CREATE, User);
    }

    return build({
      // Read https://casl.js.org/v5/en/guide/subject-type-detection#use-classes-as-subject-types for details
      detectSubjectType: (item) =>
        item.constructor as ExtractSubjectType<Subjects>,
    });
  }
}
```

And the failing test

```ts
const ability = authorizationAbilityFactory.createForUser(); // <- anonymous user

expect(ability.can(Action.READ, Collection)).toBe(false); // <- this fails
```

Comment: For now I've added a new action `Action.ReadList` but I'm not a big fan...